# how to reseed table to start at the PK 2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to reseed table to start at the PK 2?

(SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBCC RESEED:  See example here:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/15/sql-server-dbcc-reseed-table-identity-value-reset-table-identity/